# struct type conversion in C

Tags: c, sockets, struct, network-programming, type-conversion

In the below snippet , I found a sockaddr_in is type converted as sockaddr as '(struct sockaddr *) &sin' . I just want to know what are the variables that are in sockaddr_in will be mapped correspondingly to sockaddr . 
Below is the snippet.

```
struct sockaddr {
unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

// IPv4 AF_INET sockets:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

struct sockaddr_in sin;

sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(floodport);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
```

//type conversion

```
(struct sockaddr *) &sin  // what values of sockaddr_in would be mapped to sockaddr ?
```

this conversion is used in sendto() in socket programming as below .

```
sendto(s, datagram, iph->tot_len,0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin,sizeof(sin))
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: And, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The only purpose for `struct sockaddr` is to have one type to pass around to functions like `sendto()` etc.

In fact, you don't use it for other purposes, there you have [other structs](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sockaddr_inman.html) such as

- `struct sockaddr_in` for the legacy IPv4
- `struct sockaddr_in6` for IPv6
- `struct sockaddr_un` for Unix sockets
- `struct sockaddr_bth` for Bluetooth
- `struct sockaddr_storage` which is as large as the largest in your
  architecture. Can neatly be used for storing addresses whose type you
  don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The functions that use struct sockaddr will only read sa_family and do the opposite cast internally (if they understand what's inside sa_family).